# ValueError: low >= high in np.random.randint [New Type]

Tags: python, numpy, random

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

dataset_paths = glob.glob("dataset_characters/**/*.jpg")

cols=3
rows=3
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.rcParams.update({"font.size":14})
grid = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=cols,nrows=rows,figure=fig)

# create a random list of images will be displayed
np.random.seed(45)
rand = np.random.randint(0,len(dataset_paths),size=(cols*rows))
```

Error is shown below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-6eacd403c46e> in <module>
     14 # create a random list of images will be displayed
     15 np.random.seed(45)
---> 16 rand = np.random.randint(0,len(dataset_paths),size=(cols*rows))
     17 
     18 # Plot example images

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint()

_bounded_integers.pyx in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32()

ValueError: low >= high

<Figure size 720x576 with 0 Axes>
```

It works fine in the tutorial but it showing an error here... see the other answers for this error but didn't get the solution...trying to implement data visualization here

Comment: What does printing `len(dataset_paths)` give you?

Comment: @c2huc2hu It gives 0

Comment: Apparently the `glob` is not finding any files!

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out). It is also apparent that the question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` (removed).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the 'low' parameter in `np.random.randint()` is equal to or greater than the 'high' parameter.

You can see in your code that the length of `dataset_paths` is equal to 0. Therefore, this error will always occur if `dataset_path` is defined in this way, because you are not providing the actual length of dataset_paths when calling `np.random.randint()`